# PayPal REST API Show Payment Details V1 Upgrade to V2?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm upgrading my company's project and trying to upgrade from the deprecated [v1](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK) PayPal SDK to [v2](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK), everything worked out alright, until trying to migrate some old functionality to support viewing a previous payment.

The original REST Api was [Show Payment Details](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v1/#payment_get) where you would provide the `payment_id` defined as *The ID of the payment for which to show details.*

Most of the documentation indicates that the migration moves from Payments V1 to Orders V2 so I looked at the [Get](https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders_get) request which was defined as *The ID of the order for which to show details.* not quite the same so unsurprisingly it didn't work, what seemed more likely was the [Payment V2](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v2/) but they only had references to `capture_id` for the [Show captured payment details](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v2/#captures_get) and `authorization_id` for [Show details for authorized payment](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_get) (which I tried in any event to no avail).

Unfortunately PayPal's documentation is quite sparse and I haven't been able to find a proper Migration Guide for Old functionality to new Functionality, breaking changes or handling the equivalent.

I am hoping against all odds that someone has a recommendation where I can retrieve older payments information and maybe upgrade them somehow? (I'm currently considering recreating support for the deprecated API but it seems silly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear on what you're trying to accomplish and with what value, but when you capture a v2/order there are two IDs.

The ID of the order -- which was only relevant during the approval/capture process and no longer useful once complete -- and the ID of the capture which is in the response at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`.

This latter ID is the PayPal transaction ID, and the one you should persist in your database for accounting purposes; it corresponds to all the information and reports in the receiving [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) account. The v2/payments 'show captured payment details' operates with this ID and will return its status.

---

For transactions created with a previous API, use that API.

Comment: I didn't see an indication that **Order Id** is a short term **Id**, do you have a reference that you can point to that indicates it?

Comment: There is nothing useful you can do with Order Id after completion. It has served its purpose.

Comment: But as long as it isn't short term, you can use it to retrieve all nested payments, shipping information or anything else unique that a single payment cannot provide. Or am I wrong in some way?

Comment: It's not persisted. Store everything you need in your own database on completion.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but did you find anything in the documentation to indicate the lifetime of the object? I couldn't find anything anywhere. (The **Create Order** API for example specifies that the token would only be good for up to 72 hours)

Comment: It can be used for 72 hours from creation, yes. But after completion, I don't know how long it's still queryable. Maybe something like a month, IDK. You really shouldn't need to query it further after doing a capture; in fact the capture response itself should be sufficient. It's done its job at that point.